# Finding the eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix without using determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ with $\dim(V) = n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that the diagonal entries of the upper-triangular matrix of $T$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ without the use of determinants.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237746/eigenvalues-and-upper-triangular-matrices) comes pretty close to what I'm asking, but the solutions/comments assume that an **upper triangular matrix is not invertible iff there is a zero on the main diagonal**.

How do I prove this? By invertibility of a matrix $A$, I understand that $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$. Could someone please help me prove the desired statement using this definition of invertibility?

Comment: Just convince yourself that the matrix cannot have rank $n$.

Comment: if top left corner is zero then $T\mathbf e_1 =\mathbf 0$ and you are done.  Now assume top left corner is non-zero -- this sets up an induction for counting the rank -- consider leading $2\times 2$ matrix then $3\times 3$ and so on. (E.g. if second diagonal component is zero then 2nd column is linear combination of first column so linearly dependent.) The problem with the approach OP is going for is it will only directly give geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues, not algebraic multiplicities.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How?